# SQL setting start date to Friday, and read Data between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff, dateadd

I'm trying to set the start date to friday on a sql query. Which I have done as you can see below. What I need to do now is show all the GameID's between Friday and Saturday, and it refreshes every week (so that every week it shows other games that have been played in that week).

I'm a complete beginner at SQL so any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried the sql query below.

```
DECLARE @StartFriday datetime
DECLARE @EndSaturday datetime

SET DATEFIRST 6 -- Set the start of the week to Friday

SELECT *
FROM
(

SELECT  GameDate,
        DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), -5)) AS 'StartFriday', 
        DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), 1)) AS 'EndSaturday'

FROM VW_Resultaat_Score 

WHERE GameDate BETWEEN 'StartFriday' AND 'EndSaturday' --Show all GameDates between @StartFriday and @EndSaturday
)
```

I would love any help I can get!

Cheers

Comment: First off, `SET DATEFIRST 6` sets it to start Saturday, not Friday. You want to use `5`. Second, what do you get from this query?

Comment: Your `where` clause is trying to compare a date to two string literals, neither of which contain a date. As for the column aliases, may I offer some suggested reading: [Is it a String Literal or an Alias?](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/30/string-literal-alias-sql-server.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will work better:

```
DECLARE @StartFriday datetime
DECLARE @EndSaturday datetime

SET DATEFIRST 6
Set @StartFriday = DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), -5))
Set @EndSaturday = DATEADD(w, 0, DATEADD(w, DATEDIFF(w, 0,GETDATE()), 1))

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  GameDate
FROM VW_Resultaat_Score 
WHERE GameDate BETWEEN @StartFriday AND @EndSaturday
)
```

Comment: This almost works, After the second select query you added a , after GameDate which will give you an error. And I needed to add an alias after the subselect otherwise it gives you an error. But this did definately works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you will only ever need the weekend previous, this code will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM VW_Resultaat_Score
WHERE GameDate BETWEEN 
(SELECT DATEADD(d, 1 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 2, getdate())), getdate())) 
AND 
(SELECT DATEADD(d, 1 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 1, getdate())), getdate()))
```

Code looks a little crazy, but it works. If you may need to query other specific weekends, this may be an option:

```
DECLARE @getdate date
SET @getdate='2017-05-16'
SELECT *
FROM VW_Resultaat_Score
WHERE GameDate BETWEEN 
    (SELECT DATEADD(d, 1 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 2, @getdate)), @getdate)) 
    AND 
    (SELECT DATEADD(d, 1 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 1, @getdate)), @getdate))
```

Taking it a step further, you may need to report on each of these weekends. The following code gives you all the Friday Saturdays of each week for 2017.

```
WITH Fri as
(SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num)) yyyy, DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num)) weeknumber, Fridays = CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num) as Date)
FROM (SELECT TOP 366 num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.NAME)-1 FROM dbo.syscolumns a, dbo.syscolumns b) n
WHERE DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num)) = 'Friday')
,
Sat as
(SELECT weeknumber=DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num)), Saturdays = CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num) as Date)
FROM (SELECT TOP 366 num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.NAME)-1 FROM dbo.syscolumns a, dbo.syscolumns b) n
WHERE DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num)) = 'Saturday')
Select Fri.weeknumber, fri.yyyy, Fridays, Saturdays
FROM Fri
JOIN Sat on Fri.weeknumber=Sat.weeknumber
```